# Función eval() en Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Hay alguna manera de evaluar una String en Kotlin al estilo eval() de JavaScript?

Por ejemplo:

```
var str = "var x = 5"
eval(str)

println(x) //Y que muestre por pantalla 5
```

Comment: Según la documentación existe la función [eval](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.js/eval.html) dentro del [paquete](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.js/index.html) Kotlin.js que te permite lanzar javascript

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44009876/579895

Comment: @Pikoh lo he probado y no me reconoce la función `ScriptEngineManager()` no se qué jar debería de incluir en el proyecto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que buscas se llama scripting y esto es soportado desde la version 1.1 utilizando las API de [`javax.script`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/script/package-summary.html). [Aqui un ejemplo de su uso](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew11.html#javaxscript-support):

```
val engine = ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByExtension("kts")!!
engine.eval("val x = 3")
println(engine.eval("x + 2"))  // Prints out 5
```

Tambien existe un [proyecto en github](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/tree/master/libraries/examples/kotlin-jsr223-local-example) con ejemplos disponibles de como utilizar la API.